# Microsoft BizTalk server 2013 R2 trace configuration in pass the receive parameters to sender port in restful web services call

Tags: rest, visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have restful web Api that published into IIS and work properly.

Then I published my BizTalk orchestration successfully.

This is Hello World sample template in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\SDK\Samples\Orchestrations\HelloWorld

[image: web api restful web service]

My schema in receive port is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xs:schema xmlns="http://BizTalk_call_wsdn4_wsdn2.Schema2" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://BizTalk_call_wsdn4_wsdn2.Schema2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" /> 
            <xs:attribute name="price" type="xs:string" /> 
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" /> 
            <xs:attribute name="sync" type="xs:string" /> 
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is my visual studio orchestration architecture template that I used so you can find it in **hello world** sample

[image: BizTalk server 2013 orchestration]

Then this **map** in administration console pass the parameters to next step:

[image: BizTalk Map]

This schema in administration console:

[image: BizTalk schema]

These two screen shots show you that I configured my send and receive ports for calling web HTTP restful

[image: BizTalk receive port]

[image: BizTalk Send Port]

My question is about how can I trace step by step to debug my plan?

My send and receive ports in my project before publish :

[image: specify later to configure send and receive port]

How can I connect to configured project in BizTalk that those configuration after publish? How to trace? How to debug and run step by step?

Google show up in results [articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561459.aspx) that doesn't have any similarity to trace c# apps.

[image: biztalk server trace like csharp]

Comment: Are you asking in general or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: in general how can we trace these type of ports in biztalk server  that configured as "specify later" like visual studio traces like break points? or generate log ?. next question about how can we visualized threads that fire in biztalk for students in class when i teach them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tracing things through BizTalk, especially multi-threaded instances I would recommend the [BizTalk CAT Instrumentation Framework Controller](https://btscatifcontroller.codeplex.com/).

It does require you to put some lines off code in all your bits of code that you want to trace, but if you make that a standard of development it can be a useful thing to debug things at runtime in a production environment without impacting performance.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we don't 'trace' in BizTalk the same way we would trace in a plan .Net app.  You can absolutely use .Net Tracing, but...it's just a different paradigm.

You have to know your message flow and follow through the process.  Most of the time, this is in BizTalk Administrator through Tracking.  There's also the Orchestration Debugger, also in BT Admin, where you can see the Orchestrations actual flow.

Basically, this is an very broad question, but that's ok.  It hard to answer in general.  I think it would be better to try a few things, then ask about specific situations.

Comment: how can i design if i want to call web api as receive port? is this logical that  my web service return rows only when there are new rows in database?

Comment: That sounds like a question for a dedicated thread.  But, are you polling the database?  You service would return whatever you program it to return...